# 1064 SQL create table error

Tags: php, sql

```
1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''models'( 'model_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 'model_usernam' at line 1
```

I have this error when I try to create sql table.

And this is the code.. Please help..

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'models'(
    'model_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    'model_username' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'model_gender' ENUM('f','m','s','c') NOT NULL,
    'model_show' ENUM('public','private','group','away') NOT NULL,
    'model_age' INT NOT NULL,
    'model_time' INT NOT NULL,
    'model_new' TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default '0',
    'model_hd' TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default '0',
    'model_recorded' TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default '0',
    'model_image' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'model_users' INT NOT NULL,
    'model_language' VARCHAR(250),
    'model_name' VARCHAR(250),
    'model_location' VARCHAR(250),
    'model_subject' VARCHAR(250),
    'model_roomurl' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'model_roomurlrevshre' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'model_iframe' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'model_iframerevshre' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'model_birthday' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL )";
```

Comment: You are using single quotes where not quotes at all are necessary.  You probably mean back ticks, though.  I consider this frequent problem to be a typographic error and vote to close such questions.

Comment: When I first started, I didn't know that backticks were needed instead of the single quote. It's not necessarily a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use backticks for your column names instead of single-quotes.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `models`(
`model_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`model_username` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
`model_gender` ENUM('f','m','s','c') NOT NULL,
`model_show` ENUM('public','private','group','away') NOT NULL,
`model_age` INT NOT NULL, ...
```

Comment: Same thing for `'models'` there Jay ;)

Comment: Good catch @Fred-ii- I'm still only part way through my first cup this morning. :)

Comment: You're ahead of me; I haven't even had my first yet, which should be ready just........about............ now ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this i just tested it out, it works. its the issue with the backticks and single-quotes

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `models`(
    model_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    model_username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    model_gender ENUM('f','m','s','c') NOT NULL,
    model_show ENUM('public','private','group','away') NOT NULL,
    model_age INT NOT NULL,
    model_time INT NOT NULL,
    model_new TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    model_hd TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    model_recorded TINYINT(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    model_image VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    model_users INT NOT NULL,
    model_language VARCHAR(250),
    model_name VARCHAR(250),
    model_location VARCHAR(250),
    model_subject VARCHAR(250),
    model_roomurl VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    model_roomurlrevshre VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    model_iframe VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    model_iframerevshre VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    model_birthday VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL );
```